# Problem reading and rendering Spectrum

Tags: frequency-spectrum, wave

I'm now processing PCM codes extracted from .wav file and want render the spectrum myself. First I try to read a spectrum on my foobar2000 player as below.

[image]

My problem with this spectrum is: what do x-axis and y-axis represent? IIRC, the x-axis represents different frequency(or angular speed) and the scale should be whole-number times of fundamental, i.e. 50. However, when I divide next by its preceding, e.g. $94\div 69$, the outcome is roughly always 1.37. As to the y-axis, why the scale is negative? What is the calibrated value, i.e. $P_2$ in $10\log_{10}{\frac{P_1}{P_2}}$.

If I want to render the amplitude spectrum with PCM code, should some normalization be first taken(I know the original 8-bit PCM code ranges from -128 to 127, even normalized range is -1.0 to 1.0. It seems I can't use these values directly to represent amplitude of the signals)?

Thanks and Best Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The x-axis is indeed frequency, but the numbers are quite strange to me. One would expect a scale in powers of 2 (octaves) or of powers of 10 (decades).

The y-axis represents the relative magnitude of the signal at that particular frequency. The 0dB level is what you would get from a sine wave with the maximum amplitude (-1..+1). So your P2 is 1.0.

Comment: Thanks. But what if $P_1$ is 0.0? How to evaluate the $\log$? By the way, how could I determine the fundamental frequency after fourier transformation? IIRC, I will get a sequence of angular frequency after DFT.

Comment: If P1 is 0.0, the magnitude in dB would be -infinity. You'll have to define a cutoff point. Preferably one that corresponds with the dynamic range (some 48dB for 8-bit PCM).
Finding the fundamental is a different problem altogether. It involves finding the peak frequency, but ignoring the harmonics. Also there is something called the missing fundamental which makes this problem ever so interesting.

Comment: Suddenly realize that fundamental frequency of signals is different from those of DFT. Then what does the frequency $\frac{k}{N}$(correct me if wrong) used in Fourier Transform represent physically? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you (Fourier) transform N samples of a signal with a samplerate of F, then the highest frequency in the transform is F/2 (the Nyquist frequency). The N samples in the transform each represent a frequency (bin) with size of F/2N Hz. The k/N represents the kth frequency bin or kF/2N Hz.